# Using Python script how to solve my problem?

Tags: python

In one of the Quick Sight report, I have values stored under a column in the below format.

```
{
    `jeanette.underwood@crowe.com-delete`
    `isaac@accumulus.cpa-delete`
    `veronica@accumulus.co-delete`
    `BDengler@alloysilverstein.com-delete-delete-delete-delete-delete`
    `mhahn@andersonadvisors.com-delete-delete`
}
```

I would like the final output to be displayed like this:

```
{
    `crowe.com`
    `accumulus.cpa`
    `accumulus.co`
    `alloysilverstein.com`
    `andersonadvisors.com`
}
```

Using python script how can I achieve the above output?

The current python script being used is this:

```
trim(substring({Reg Email Id},locate({Reg Email Id},'@',1)+1,strlen({Reg Email Id})-locate({Reg Email Id},'@',1)))
```

The output of the above script is this:

```
`crowe.com-delete`
`accumulus.cpa-delete`
`accumulus.co-delete`
`alloysilverstein.com-delete-delete-delete-delete-delete`
`andersonadvisors.com-delete-delete`
```

Eventually, I want the output to be in this format:

```
{
    `crowe.com`
    `accumulus.cpa`
    `accumulus.co`
    `alloysilverstein.com`
    `andersonadvisors.com`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe is not the correct way but you could use .replace('-delete', '') in the output

Comment: where do I use '.replace('-delete', ") ? Can you write the script? I'm new to python.

Comment: what kind of data is the final variable? string? list? dict?

Comment: string like this: 
    `crowe.com`
    `accumulus.cpa`
    `accumulus.co`
    `alloysilverstein.com`
    `andersonadvisors.com`

Comment: if you only have one string variable you can use:

yourvariable = yourvariable.replace('-delete', '')

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to process a string in Python and remove certain parts of it, you can use the re module which allows you to use regular expressions.

For your specific problem, you can use the following Python script:

```
import re

# Original string
s = "{ jeanette.underwood@crowe.com-delete isaac@accumulus.cpa-delete veronica@accumulus.co-delete BDengler@alloysilverstein.com-delete-delete-delete-delete-delete mhahn@andersonadvisors.com-delete-delete }"

# Using regular expression to find and replace
cleaned_s = re.sub(r'(\w+)@(\w+\.\w+)-delete', r'\2', s)

# Printing the cleaned string
print(cleaned_s)
```

The re.sub() function is used to replace the parts of the string. The pattern (\w+)@(\w+.\w+)-delete is used to match the email addresses, and the replacement r'\2' is used to keep only the domain of the email addresses.

Please note that this assumes all the emails follow the format username@domain-delete. If there are any variations, the regular expression would need to be adjusted accordingly.

Also note that this code snippet does not handle the -delete-delete-delete cases you have mentioned in your example. If you want to handle these cases and remove any number of repeated -delete strings, you can modify the regular expression to (\w+)@(\w+.\w+)(-delete)+.

```
import re

# Original string
s = "{ jeanette.underwood@crowe.com-delete isaac@accumulus.cpa-delete veronica@accumulus.co-delete BDengler@alloysilverstein.com-delete-delete-delete-delete-delete mhahn@andersonadvisors.com-delete-delete }"
```

Like this:

```
# Using regular expression to find and replace
cleaned_s = re.sub(r'(\w+)@(\w+\.\w+)(-delete)+', r'\2', s)

# Printing the cleaned string
print(cleaned_s)
```

Comment: I do not have the option to use "re.sub()" function in Quick Sight.

Comment: Sorry, QuickSight uses a SQL-like syntax for creating calculated fields, which doesn't have an exact equivalent of Python's re.sub() function.
However, it does have replace function, which can replace all instances of a substring within a string.
You can achieve similar results by creating a calculated field using replace function to replace -delete with an empty string. 
ie:
replace({your_field_name}, '-delete', '')

Hope it helps.

Comment: using the replace({Reg Email Id}, '-delete', '') script, I was able to replace the '-delete'. 

Now the output looks like this:

bradleyya1989@gmail.com
Joe@MilkusTrierCPA.com
bwright@abclegal.com
jeanette.underwood@crowe.com

Comment: you can use a combination of 'substring' and 'locate' functions to achieve this.
look a this: 
substring({Reg Email Id}, locate({Reg Email Id}, '@', 1) + 1, strlen({Reg Email Id}))

Answer (score 1):

You can use split method. Add `.split('<delimiter>')` to the end of a string to split it to a list based on the delimiter.
For example.

```
mystring = 'jeanette.underwood@crowe.com-delete'

# create a list by spliting the string where have the @ symbol.
# you will get ['jeanette.underwood', 'crowe.com-delete']
# from this take the second item by id. 'crowe.com-delete'
# then split that where you have a hyphon '-'.
# you will get ['crowe.com', 'delete']
# and take the first item by id. 'crowe.com'
result = mystring.split('@')[1].split('-')[0]
```